# Statistical test for cumulative curves

Tags: statistical-significance

I have three treatment groups represented in three cumulative curves. What is the best test to show differences among them.Knowing that treatments were observed cumulatively for only seven days.

Comment: What is the outcome you are measuring in each group? Is it time to some event?